# Remover arquivo do input

Tags: jquery

Estou montando um formulário de upload múltiplo de arquivos.
O que tenho até agora está quase bom.
Ao fazer o upload, é gerada a opção de remover o arquivo, antes de enviar o formulário (um preview).
Está removendo do preview, mas não está removendo do input.
Se fosse limpar tudo o que está no input, bastaria dar o comando "$JQuery('#image_file').val("");", por exemplo.
Mas, no caso, eu precisaria excluir do input o mesmo arquivo que eu exclui no preview.
Seria possível excluir apenas o determinado arquivo no input?

Segue o que fiz até o momento.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Multiplo</title>

<!-- Jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.agenciamove.com.br/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Boostrap -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   /****** Upload múltiplo ******/  
   $(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
     $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
      filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
      var f = files[i]
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
       var file = e.target;
       $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
       "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
       "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remover imagem</span>" +
       "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
       $(".remove").click(function(){
        $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
       });
      });
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
     });
    } else {
     alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
    }
   }); 
   /****** Upload múltiplo ******/     
  </script> 

  <!-- ****** Upload múltiplo ****** --> 
  <style type="text/css">
   input[type="file"] {
    display: block;
   }
   .imageThumb {
    max-height: 75px;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
   .pip {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
   }
   .remove {
    display: block;
    background: #444;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
   .remove:hover {
    background: white;
    color: black;
   }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
<div class="field" align="left">
  <h3>Upload your images</h3>
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
</div>
  
 </div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolveu teu problema?